# Location Reload Seting the page

Tags: javascript, ajax

I'm using location.reload in js but I wanna set the page a i wanna reload, this is my function

```
 success: function (data) {
                alert("Andamento concluido nos seguinte processos: " + data.ids_processos);
                location.reload('/admin/carregamentop/index');
                return false;
            }
```

How can i set the page?

Comment: Are you perhaps looking to redirect? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/503093/how-do-i-redirect-to-another-webpage

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I redirect to another webpage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/503093/how-do-i-redirect-to-another-webpage)

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of methods to do this ,use what is most suitable for you

visit  https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/obj_location.asp